# Can't load option choices into SelectInput with fetch()

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I'm pushing data fetched from REST API but get undefined. How can I get this data in the right way?

My responde from API:

```
[{
"id": 1,
"positionName": "Accounting Assistant III"
}, {
"id": 2,
"positionName": "Web Developer III"
}, {
"id": 3,
"positionName": "Graphic Designer"}]
```

My code in React:

```
const getPosistions = async () => {
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/positions/');
    const myJson = await response.json();
    return myJson;
}

var positionsChoices;
getPosistions().then(function (result) {
    positionsChoices = result;
});

const EmployeeCreate = props => (
    <Create {...props}>
        <SimpleForm>
            <SelectInput
                source="id"
                choices={positionsChoices}
                optionText="positionName"
                optionValue="id"
            />
        </SimpleForm>
    </Create>
);
```

Answer (score 4):

React does not re-render when a mutable variable changes, unless you explicitly set new value of a `prop`, `state` or `context`. For this case, `state` seems most appropriate - please read [State and Lifecycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) to learn more.

As a bonus, if you want to see React Hooks in action:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

const getPosistions = async () => {
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/positions/');
    const myJson = await response.json();
    return myJson;
}

const EmployeeCreate = props => (
    const [positionsChoices, setPositionsChoices] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {
      getPosistions().then((result) => setPositionsChoices(result));
    }, []);

    <Create {...props}>
        <SimpleForm>
            <SelectInput
                source="id"
                choices={positionsChoices}
                optionText="positionName"
                optionValue="id"
            />
        </SimpleForm>
    </Create>
);
```